# Change texture in libgdx to create animation

Tags: android, libgdx

what would be the best way to change a texture of a unit?

I have this controllable bird, and when you press to the left of it, I want to change texture so that the bird is tilted to the left, the same goes for when pressing to the right. basicly, I want to change the image of the bird.

I have got it working, but can't help to think there is a better way to do it, this is what I have:

```
Texture birdOriginal;
Texture birdLeft;
Texture batRight;

birdOriginal = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("textures/birdNew.png"));
birdLeft = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("textures/birdLeft.png"));
birdRight = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("textures/birdRight.png"));

//psuedo code
if (birdPosition > touchPosition){
  birdImage = birdRight;
}
if (birdPosition < touchPosition){
  birdImage = birdRight;
}

if (!Gdx.input.isTouched()){
  birdImage = birdOriginal;
}
```

As I said, this works, but I am asking because I wan't to make the wings go up and down everytime I press the screen, and I don't think I can swap between textures to do that.

thanks for listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the same texture instead of multiple ones, declare it as a sprite.
With sprites you can manipulate the image much easier such as rotation and flipping.

You could also keep using texture and use the following

draw(Texture texture, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight, boolean flipX, boolean flipY)

```
<code>
Sprite bird = new Sprite(birdTexture);
bird.setFlip(true, false);
bird.rotate(0.45);
</code>
```

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html

Comment: oh nice, thanks! I was thinking it's not necessary to load several textures, this solves that.